# Not able to install 'slack' through snap

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, snap, apparmor, slack

While installing slack from snap store using the command line (sudo snap install slack --classic), I get the following errors. Please help me resolve this.

```
  error: cannot perform the following tasks:
 - Setup snap "slack" (49) security profiles (cannot setup profiles for snap "slack": cannot load apparmor profiles: exit status 1

 apparmor_parser output: AppArmor parser error for
 /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-update-ns.slack in
 /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-update-ns.slack at line 8: Could
 not open 'tunables/global' 


AppArmor parser error for
 /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.slack.slack in
 /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.slack.slack at line 2: Could not
 open 'tunables/global' )
```

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with AppArmor. Since AppArmor is installed by default, you need to remove and reinstall its profiles:

```
sudo apt purge apparmor-profiles
sudo apt install apparmor-profiles
```

Then you can snap install the slack again.

Comment: Does not appear to currently work.  Any other suggestions?